# PHP error crashing code

Tags: php, wordpress, crash, instagram-api

I have come to some problems. I've made a wordpress plugin, which automatically gets the most 20 recent Instagram posts and then, in theory, it should make me let to insert the newest image as a shortcode in to the post. 
Now, the code to reproduce this is:

```
//define Access token
$accesst= "PUT YOUR INSTAGRAM ACCESS TOKEN HERE";
//userid
$userid= YOUR INSTAGRAM USER ID HERE;
//image count to get
$count=20;
//get api contents
$content = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='.$accesst.'&count='.$count);
//converting JSON to object
$standardres = json_decode($content, true);
//array method
foreach($standardres['data'] as $photo) {
   $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($photo['images']['standard_resolution']['url']));
   $images[] = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $imageData . '" />';
}



//create functions for shortcodes
function fone($images){
    return $images[0]; //naudok tik [one]
} 
//shortcodes
add_shortcode( 'one', 'fone');
?>
```

Basically, I get an error message displaying:

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in D:\XEMP\htdocs\xd\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\insta-live\insta-live.php on line 29
```

Any ideas how to solve this? A `var_dump()` gives me the images above the header.. And please don't point me to unitiliazed string offset thread, because i don't really see it as the same problem.

Comment: Something is being sent in empty.

Comment: which is line 29

Comment: return $images[0];  -   this is line 29

Comment: `$images` appears out of scope. Is this exactly as it's written in the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used WordPress for awhile but `$images` looks out of scope. I would maybe try wrapping your API work and referencing it inside the shortcode function, something like below. I would research best practice on this type of thing related to WordPress:

```
if(!class_exists('MyAPI')) {
    class MyAPI
    {
        # Create an image storage
        protected static $imgs;
        # Access your API
        public function callInstagram($accesst = 'PUT YOUR INSTAGRAM ACCESS TOKEN HERE',$userid = 'YOUR INSTAGRAM USER ID HERE')
        {
            # If you have already set it with content, return it
            if(!empty(self::$imgs['instagram']))
                return self::$imgs['instagram'];
            //image count to get
            $count = 20;
            //get api contents
            $content = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='.$accesst.'&count='.$count);
            //converting JSON to object
            $standardres = json_decode($content, true);
            //array method
            foreach($standardres['data'] as $photo) {
                $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($photo['images']['standard_resolution']['url']));
                $images[] = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $imageData . '" />';
            }
            # Set the instagram images store
            if(!empty($images))
                # Assign
                self::$imgs['instagram'] = $images;
            # Return the images if set
            return (isset(self::$imgs['instagram']))? self::$imgs['instagram'] : false;
        }
        # Return the images
        public function getInstagramImg($img = false)
        {
            $imgs = $this->callInstagram();
            if($img !== false)
                return (isset($imgs[$img]))? $imgs[$img] : false;
            # Return all
            return $imgs;
        }
    }
}

//create functions for shortcodes
function fone()
{
    # Create API instance
    $Instagram = new MyAPI();
    # Send back the first image in the list
    return $Instagram->getInstagramImg('0');
} 
//shortcodes
add_shortcode('one', 'fone');
```

One last note, I am assuming that your API work is correct, you should check that it works first before you start going all crazy trying to figure out why the `$images` doesn't work. Use `print_r()` to see if it returns the correct info from Instagram.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `$images` before you loop through and append values, especially since you want to pass it as a parameter. Before the `foreach` loop, add:

```
$images = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you have an issue with the input going into the `fone()` function which is triggering that error.

Try to perform an `isset()` check within that function to make sure the item does actually exist before you try to return it.

Example...

```
//create functions for shortcodes
function fone($images){
    if (isset($images[0])) {
        return $images[0]; //naudok tik [one]
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Now I get nothing.

Comment: Then it's definitely related to the value of `$images`. This would indicate you are passing an empty object/array/string of some sort into that function. Maybe if Instagram doesn't return any data?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, check if you want to see the whole code in working state:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Instagram Feed Embed
Description: Embed a live photo to wordpress posts from your feed
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Jacob Stankaitis
Author URL: https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/~017e31b991d3d0f253
*/
//define Access token
$accesst= "PUT_YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE";
//userid
$userid= PUT_YOUR_USER_ID_HERE;
//image count to get
$count=20;
//get api contents
$content = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='.$accesst.'&count='.$count);
//converting JSON to object
$standardres = json_decode($content, true);
//array method
$images= array();
foreach($standardres['data'] as $photo) {
   $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($photo['images']['standard_resolution']['url']));
   array_push ($images, '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $imageData . '" />');
}

//create functions for shortcodes with definition
function fone(){
    global $images;
    return ($images[0]);
} 
function ftwo(){
global $images;
return $images[1];
}
function fthree(){
    global $images;
return $images [2];

}
function ffour(){
    global $images;
return $images [3];
}
function ffive(){
    global $images;
return $images [4];
}
function fsix(){
    global $images;
return $images [5];
}
function fseven(){
    global $images;
return $images [6];
}
function feight(){
    global $images;
return $images [7];
}
function fnine(){
    global $images;
return $images [8];
}
function ften(){
    global $images;
return $images[9];
}
function feleven(){
    global $images;
return $images [10];
}
function ftwelve(){
    global $images;
return $images [11];
}
function fthirteen(){
    global $images;
return $images[12];
}
function ffourteen(){
    global $images;
return $images [13];
}
function ffifteen(){
    global $images;
return $images [14];
}
function fsixteen(){
    global $images;
return $images [15];
}
function fseventeen(){
    global $images;
return $images [16];
}
function feighteen(){
    global $images;
return $images [17];
}
function fnineteen(){
    global $images;
return $images [18];
}
function ftwenty(){
    global $images;
return $images [19];
}

//create shortcode
add_shortcode( 'one', 'fone');
add_shortcode( 'two', 'ftwo');
add_shortcode( 'three', 'fthree');
add_shortcode( 'four', 'ffour');
add_shortcode( 'five', 'ffive');
add_shortcode( 'six', 'fsix');
add_shortcode( 'seven', 'fseven');
add_shortcode( 'eight', 'feight');
add_shortcode( 'nine', 'fnine');
add_shortcode( 'ten', 'ften');
add_shortcode( 'eleven', 'feleven');
add_shortcode( 'twelve', 'ftwelve');
add_shortcode( 'thirteen', 'fthirteen');
add_shortcode( 'fourteen' , 'ffourteen');
add_shortcode( 'fifteen', 'ffifteen');
add_shortcode( 'sixteen', 'fsixteen');
add_shortcode( 'seventeen', 'fseventeen');
add_shortcode( 'eighteen', 'feighteen');
add_shortcode( 'nineteen', 'fnineteen');
add_shortcode( 'twenty', 'ftwenty');

?>
```

If you'd like to use it, you're free to do so, just replace the "PUT_YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE" and "PUT_YOUR_USER_ID_HERE" with your Instagram Access token and your user ID!